# delete leading characters

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm a noob to actionscript so this should be easy:

How do I delete leading characters from a string? I have a string that contains (at times) both numeric & non-numeric characters. If I want to delete all the leading 9's, how would I do that?

```
var testVar:String = '999998gjek74k';
```

I want the testVar to be 'gjek74k'.

So far, I have (though not working):

```
var testVar:String = '999998gjek74k';
testVar.replace(/^0/g, "");
```

Comment: ^\d*

would be all leading numerics i think...

Comment: testVar.replace(/^[0-9]+/g, ''); would also do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.replace` doesn't modify the string. It *returns* the replaced string.

```
testVar = testVar.replace(/^\d+/, '');
```

(Also the pattern `/^0/g` is wrong, as commented by @santa).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are testing the variables and not multiple lines:

```
private var testVar = testVar.replace(/^\d*(.+)$/,"$1");
```